# how do I subscribe to an event in raised in another assembly

Tags: c#, events, assemblies, solution

I have a solution which contains 3 project.  One project handles asynchronous communinications.  When it has completed it's callback, it raises an event SomethingCompleted.
How do I subscribe to this event from another project in the same solution?

I have the event handlers built in the receiving project but it does not see the event in the sending project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the class raising the event to register an event handler.

Once you have that, it's done like registering any other event handler:

```
foo.SomethingCompleted += (sender, e) => this.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing special about events raised in a separate assembly, unless the event itself is declared with the `internal` access modifier. Check that it's public.

To give an example of what I mean, I'm sure you don't think twice about subscribing to `Button.Click` - but `Button` is in a different assembly, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The event must be declared as public in the class which defines it:

```
public class Something
{
  public event EventHandler SomethingCompleted;
}
```

You can then subscribe to it just as to any other event:

```
Something s = ...;
s.SomethingCompleted += SomeEventHandler;
```